# Don't rebuild vendor entry in a CommonChunkPlugin setup

Tags: webpack

I've a webpack config that looks quite like the one from the CommonsChunkPlugin example:

```
entry: {
  vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "prop-types"],
  app: "./entry"
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "vendor",
    minChunks: Infinity,
  })
]
```

the vendor chunk will never change, so I like to build that once and keep it. From there on I like to only bundle the app entry (of cause with vendor packages excluded).

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Did you find an answer?
Is this still relavent?